Exim4 with Too Many Connections
In this post I asked what caused the "Too many connections" error in Exim4.
Using smtp_accept_max can indeed help, but it still doesn't help me 100%. Because there could be a DDoS attack and I have no idea that this is the cause.
My main questions are:
1 - How can I see how many connections are open in Exim4?
2 - How can I know which IP is opening the most connections?
3 - Is it possible to know which domain is sending the most emails or the email address that is receiving the most emails?

You should have the EXIM utilities on your system already? If you don't, you really should get them on there! They've got neato utilities that likely do all the things you wished you could do?
Check them out! Dig more into things like eximstats for what you're looking for. You may be able to discover other issues with something like exigrep, to look for specific things in your EXIM logs? It's fun stuff!
https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-exim_utilities.html
